# Marketing cloud System date vs Day light saving (Control via SQL)

Tags: marketing-cloud, soql, sql

I have a landing DE which have a field SystemDate and that is default to Current date. I need to write a SQL which pick data from landing DE and push into Y DE.

Our SFMC stack is in Central time zone. Currently CST vs EST (day light saving on) is 1 one hour difference but in standard time it will be two hours. And currently SFMC is saving in two hours difference which means standard time, they don't consider day light saving.

Is their is a way to handle all this via SQL that when I push data into Y DE the systemdate is converted into EST timezone while automatically taking care of standard vs day light saving time difference.

I already tried using AT TIME ZONE function in SQL but seems like it does not consider standard vs day light saving time difference? Is their any other method?

Thanks.

Comment: please check this:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316792/im-trying-to-get-the-time-now-using-amp-script-in-marketing-cloud/316793#316793
- and this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309698/customize-the-default-value-in-the-date-field/309749#309749

- in a nutshell: in most cases, storing dates as system time (UTC-6) is the better option. Injecting local times into a system running on a different servertime will cause more harm than benefit. Only convert when you need to e.g. extract data.